# Any good site which provied unique app demos of AR made or can be made in android

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am thinking to make a AR app in android. Before that just wanted to know how far AR havr reached in android..can anyone pls help me out..by providing some good site which provides realy cool ideas for AR.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Some hints http://bit.ly/T1KXkS

Comment: Thanx for your quick respose..But realy didn't need such type of answers..even i know dat osam ideas are not shared..but for starters ofcourse der would be something interesting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look a [this library](http://code.google.com/p/mixare/). It's an open source project and it's rather easy to work with.